# Hyperledger Fabric is fragile with CouchDb on a single node?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am developing an application using Hyperledger Fabric and I have built the Node.js client that exposes the API to make calls to the blockchain, which is up with the startFabric.sh script.

I am using CouchDB and all of the dockers that we need. I have only 1 peer, so 1 node in my network. This is a very simple one.

I thought that having a Blockchain with Hyperledger makes my data persistent. But I modified data inside CouchDB and if I query the ledger I get the modified data.
How is it possible?
This is not a Blockchain.

Can anyone explain?

Here is what I did in order to let you better understand the problem.
I have created my Entity invoking the API, the result from the blockchain is that the transaction has been submitted:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DDcM.png

And in fact, if I use the query API to get this entity, I receive this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzUlX.png

But we can check it also on the blockchain since I have the docker in log mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyIqc.png
So, until here, everything seems fine.

Now I open CouchDb and I see that my data are stored here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKui1.png

I open the entity Try2 and I modify the Owner and Location parameters, then I save:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbEiK.png

This should not be possible inside a blockchain. I am modifying data and no new transaction have been done, so how this is possible?

If I query the blockchain now, I get my modified data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ9GV.png

Am I missing some point or this should not be possible to do inside a blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

You are having just one peer and thus your [endorsement policy](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/endorsement-policies.html#endorsement-policies) would be such that if this peer endorses a transaction, that transaction would be valid.

However, in realtime use-cases, there are multiple peers owned by different organizations. And the endorsement policies are such that the majority or all the endorsing peers have to endorse the transaction for the transaction to be deemed valid.

For example, consider a consortium of 3 organizations, Org1, Org2, and Org3. Each of them has one endorsing peer, namely, Org1Peer1, Org2Peer1, and Org3Peer1. And the endorsing policy is set such that a transaction is valid only if all these peers endorse the transaction. Here, assume that you're the admin of Org1.

Now, for any valid transaction to be committed to the ledger, it has to pass through broadly 4 stages:

1. Endorsing
2. Inspecting the endorsement responses and proposing the transaction
3. Ordering
4. Validation and Commit

For your question, we need to look at stage 1 and 2. In Endorsing stage, all the endorsing peers, Org1Peer1, Org2Peer1, and Org3Peer1, has to simulate the transaction and create a [Read-Write set](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/readwrite.html). Here, endorsing peer utilizes the values stored in the State Database (for example, CouchDB) for creating this set. Broadly, read set contains the state value of an asset before the simulation and write set contains the state value of an asset after the simulation.

Further, all these endorsing peers send their read-write set to the client from where the transaction is initiated. Here, the read-write set sent by all the endorsing peers is inspected and compared. Now, since the endorsing policy required all the peers had to endorse the transaction, the read-write set of all the peers has to be exactly the same. Meaning, all the endorsing peer should be having same values in state database before simulation and should result in the same state values after simulation. If the read-write set differs, the proposal is not generated and the transaction is rejected.

Thus, if you, being an admin of Org1, updated values in the state database, then, during the endorsing phase, your peer Org1Peer1 will generate different Read-Write sets from that of Org2Peer1 and Org3Peer1. And the transaction proposal will not be submitted to the Ordering service (stage 3).

Note, the client can choose not to inspect the responses (read-write set) and yet forward the transaction proposal. This proposal would, however, be inspected at the Validation and Commit stage. Here, the transaction will be marked invalid since the read-write set differs and will be committed to the ledger.

You can get more clarity by reading about [Transaction Flow](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html#transaction-flow).

Comment: `Query` transactions do not need to be endorsed by endorsing peers!

Comment: Yes, you're right, Query transactions do not need to be endorsed. However, it is about the rogue data that is lying in the state database. Here, it's only one peer, so it might not have a bigger effect. However, if there are multiple peers, then Query transaction will result in different data for different peers which again lead to different Read-Write sets during the next transaction.

Comment: The information you provide is not wrong. I agree that the real-life blockchain network will not have only one peer/org. But the question is not about the updating transactions. The information you gave might confuse the audience

Comment: Maybe I explained a little more. However, I'm trying to cover the point in this point in the question: "I thought that having a Blockchain with Hyperledger makes my data persistent. But I modified data inside CouchDB and if I query the ledger I get the modified data. How is it possible? This is not a Blockchain." I wrote about updating transactions because that is when the consensus mechanism of Hyperledger Fabric comes in picture to indicate rogue data.

Comment: So until I got only 1 node, I can modify my world state and since I am the only one endorsing and validating transactions, I can validate my own transactions, right? So basically in order to achieve a very immutable ledger, I should have more than 1 node, right? But we said that if I modify my data, even if I have more nodes, and then I query the ledger... I am actually querying the world state and I get my modified data. This is wrong, a peer could modify this data in order to show what he want and other peers do not know about the fact that he returned his modifying data. How to solve this?

Comment: `Query` API has a `targets` parameter, where you can query multiple peers. After getting the response, you could compare the result between peers to make sure that the data is true.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a `Query` transaction, the Peer will get the latest state of the argument, which is located in `World State`. This part makes the availability of the network better.

By default, the system uses LevelDB for `World State` and CouchDB is an option ([more info](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/ledger.html#state-database)).

For that reason, when you modify the value at CouchDB on a single peer, only the `World State` is modified, not the `Ledger`. This will not break the chain!

You can read more about the `Ledger` concept of Hyperledger Fabric [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/ledger/ledger.html).

Hope this can help!

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it! But you mean that not using CouchDB, so using only LevelDB, I can avoid this problem?

Comment: And, let me ask another question: I read all of the Ledger documentation you sent, but this is not clear to me: if I modify the world state only and not the ledger, at what point the application realize that the hash of the world state doesn't match the hash on the ledger because I have modified some data?

Comment: - CouchDB and LevelDB are just options to save the world state, so it is the same.
- These databases are NoSQL. The data will be stored as (key - value) pair and there is no `hash` here.
=> You have to query to other peers to make sure that the data has not been modified